# Invalid Arrary Assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, project

im doing a project for my C++ class and I am having problems with this one particular function. I keep getting the error "invalid array assigment and I dont know why. I am just trying to swap positions into a temp variable and swap back to display this information in descending order. the array dateAdded is an array with Chars. I appreciate the help guys

```
void repAge(){
    cout << "You selected Listing by Age" << endl;

  int i;
  int pos;
  string temp;
  bool swap;

  // Look for empty row
    pos = -1;
  // look for an empty book row (title[i][0] == '\0')
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (bookTitle[i][0] == '\0') {
      pos = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Now pos is last available value.
 do
 {
  swap = false;
  for (int count = 0; count < (pos - 1); count++)
  {
      if (dateAdded[count] < dateAdded[count+1])
      {
          temp = dateAdded[count];
          dateAdded[count] = dateAdded[count+1];
          dateAdded[count+1] = temp;
          swap = true;
      }
  }
  } while (swap);


  for (i = 0; i< pos; i++) {

    while (bookTitle[i] != '\0') {
    // print it out
    cout << "Title: " << bookTitle[i] << endl;
    cout << "ISBN: " << isbn[i] << endl;
    cout << "Quantity-On-Hand: " << qtyOnHand[i] << endl;
    cout << "Wholesale Cost: " << wholesale[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;


      break;
    }
  }
```

The exact error messages that pop up are "invalid array assignment" or "invalid conversion from char* to char".

the array is declared as dateAdded[20][11] and the lines that do not work are the these

```
   temp= dateAdded[count]; 
   dateAdded[count] = dateAdded[count+1]; 
   dateAdded[count+1] = temp;
```

Comment: A) Can we have the exact error message, B) On what line does this happen?

Comment: Which line is giving you the invalid array assignment?  And what are the types of all the variables you're using?

Comment: Your arrays are not declared at all

Comment: Also, the following line `while (bookTitle[i] != '\0')` in the lower loop should probably be `if (bookTitle[i][0] != '\0')`.

Comment: What is the exact declaration of `dateAdded`?

Comment: Would be nice to have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please, if you need to sort something, using a library.  `<algorithm>` includes nearly all the sorting algorithms you will ever need, because there are only three algorithms you can ever possibly need: the fast sort, the stable sort, and the high-volume sort.  Secondly, use C++'s object-orientedness, please.  Structs are so easy to do, and would make a world of difference in your code.  Thord:  Comments are for explaining _why_, not _how_.  Comments should add information not already in the code, there is no reason to clutter your code with 'translations'.

Answer (score 1):

You say `dateAdded` is an array of chars - then, at least the following line will fail since `temp` is declared as `string`:

```
dateAdded[count+1] = temp;
```

Use something like

```
dateAdded[count+1] = temp[0];
```

Probably it is even better to declare `temp` as `char` - there is no reason to use `string` to temporarily store an element of a `char` array.